# insert a number before each number in the field according to iterations. Python

Tags: python, list

I need to insert a number before each number in the field according to the iterations.
Something like a counter

my input

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

This is my output

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4...
...
```

I need

```
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33
14 24 34...
...
```

This is my code

```
    c1=np.array([w])
    c1 = [int(i) for i in c1[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
    c1=np.array([c1]*3)
    c1=np.transpose(c1)
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you want, but you can achieve a similar effect with:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (j+1)*10 + (i+1), (4, 3), dtype=int)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[11 21 31]
 [12 22 32]
 [13 23 33]
 [14 24 34]]
```

And you can modify the function according to your input, however you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Martix operation,

```
import numpy as np
c1=np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
c1+10*np.ones((4,1))*((1,2,3))
```

result

```
array([[11., 21., 31.],
       [12., 22., 32.],
       [13., 23., 33.],
       [14., 24., 34.]])
```